# convert one string to array with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this:

```
data="{'year':'1990/01/01','income':1990/02/01,'expenses':1000668},{'year':'1990/03/01','income':1000778,'expenses':1000778}"
```

I want to set it on one array like this:

```
var chart_data = [data];
```

how can I do this?

Comment: Exactly like that. `chart_data` will be an array with one element, the string. But I assume you want to create an array of objects instead? Please post the expected outcome you want to have.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question... but do you understand JSON? If not... I bet if you read up on JSON, a solution will come to you.

Comment: Is your string in JSON format or is it just like how you have typed it? cause that format is not JSON.

Comment: You're also missing quotes around the first `income` value or the value is completely wrong in your example

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that first `income` value is meant to be either quoted or a numeric value, try this out

```
var chart_data = JSON.parse('[' + data.replace(/'/g, '"') + ']')
```

I had to convert all the single-quotes to double in order to make the string valid for JSON parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is almost JSON so you can manipulate it to match that format and then use [`JSON.parse()`](http://www.javascripture.com/JSON#parse) to convert it to a Javascript object.

The first issue is you need to convert `'` to `"` because JSON uses `"` to wrap strings.  You can use [String.replace()](http://www.javascripture.com/String#replace) to do this.

You also have several objects in the one string, but JSON can only give you one result.  You can wrap the string in `[]` to get `JSON.parse()` to give you an array containing your objects.

The last thing I saw was the income for the first item had some loose `/`s which are not allowed in JSON.  You'll need to wrap the income in `"` or remove the `/`s.

Here's an example:

```
var data = "{'year':'1990/01/01','income':19900201,'expenses':1000668},{'year':'1990/03/01','income':1000778,'expenses':1000778}";

data = '[' + data.replace(/'/g, '"') + ']';

var chart_data = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: thank u for your answer.but when I use this code It doesn't recognize JSON

Comment: What are you using to run the code?  What browser, version of node, etc?

Comment: intelliJ and tomcat,InternetExplorer 9,KasperSky